# Can not deploy python container by kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I try to deploy python container by kubernetes in AWS environment.
For testing I use this command: kubectl apply -f templates/deployment.yaml

I still get status and it restart in loop: CrashLoopBackOff

default     sbs-python-5d8f87b5c8-xbqd7   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          5s

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sbs-python
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sbs-python
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sbs-python
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sbs-python
        image: python:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

Comment: Could you take a look at the logs for the pod through `kubectl logs sbs-python-5d8f87b5c8-xbqd7`?

Comment: That error message means nothing more or less than "the container exited"; usually things managed by Deployments should stay running as long as they can.  Since you're running the unmodified Docker Hub `python` image that's not surprising.  Do you mean to set `image:` to something containing your application code?